# Check if ALL elements of list A within list B

Tags: python

I have done my research, however all these techniques return true, i need them to return false.

```
print set([2, 2]).issubset([2, 3, 3]) #returns True
print set([2, 3, 3]).issuperset(set([2, 2])) #returns True
print all(x in {2, 3, 3} for x in [2, 2]) #returns True
print set([2, 2]) <= set([2, 3, 3]) #returns True
```

The lists I'm comparing have duplicate numbers

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)(acts as a multiset).

Comment: You haven't labeled your lists. All those tests work, at potentially different efficiency, but I can't tell if you're testing what you think you are. Is your issue that you want them to hold at least as many of each item as the other collection?

Comment: Conversion to `set` removes duplicates and that is why they return `True`. Compare them as `list`s; that is without converting.

Comment: `sorted(lst1) == sorted(lst2)` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands They can also be sub`list`s.. Why `==`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Maybe, I don't know what they're asking exactly

Comment: why not just `set([2,2]) & set([2,3,3])` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `list.count` inside of the `all` function:

```
all(l1.count(i) <= l2.count(i) for i in set(l1))
```

For every element in `l1`, this will check if there is at least as many ocurences in `l2`.
If any element of `l1` appears fewer times in `l2`, then the `all` function will return `False`.
The conversion of `l1` into a `set` prevents the number of iterations from increasing when `l1` consists in a large number of the same value.

Test:

```
>>> f = lambda l1, l2: all(l1.count(i) <= l2.count(i) for i in set(l1))
>>> f([2, 2], [2, 3, 3])
False
>>> f([2, 2], [2, 2, 3])
True
```

Comment: I suggest changing `for i in l1` to `for i in set(l1)`. Otherwise, for items that appear multiple times in `l1`, it will be checked multiple times. If `l1` consists only of a single value, this has cubic rather than quadratic time.

Comment: Although even with that change, Ev. Kounis answer is even better as it is linear rather than quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still uncertain what you're really asking. Let's go with:

```
A = [2,2]
B = [2,3,3]
```

And the question being if you can make A by choosing without replacement out of B. That is, not only should the items in A be a subset of those in B, there must be at least as many of each in B as there are in A.

One way to test this is using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
countsA = Counter(A)
countsB = Counter(B)
difference = countsA - countsB # any extra items in A
print difference, not difference
```

Output: `Counter({2: 1}) False`

Since collections are true if they contain anything, we can negate it for the `False` value you asked for. This difference can also be used to show exactly which items A had that couldn't be taken out of B, in this case 1 count of the item 2.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
a = [2, 2]
b = [2, 3, 3]

from collections import Counter as cC

fa = cC(a)
print(fa)  # Counter({2: 2})
fb = cC(b)
print(fb)  # Counter({3: 2, 2: 1})

test = all(fa[entry] <= fb.get(entry, -1e+30) for entry in fa)

print(test)  # False
```

Or according to what @ChrisRand said in the comments:

```
test = fa - fb == {}
print(test)  # False
```

Comment: `Counter`s support subtraction

Comment: "Both inputs and outputs may be zero or negative." https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.subtract

Comment: While that is true for `update` and `subtract`, it is not so for `-` (under mathematical operations, a few paragraphs down).

Comment: Agreed @YannVernier  .

Comment: `Counter({3: 2, 2: 1}) - Counter({2: 2})` -> `Counter({3: 2})` and not `Counter({3: 2, 2: -1})`

Comment: I meant like `c = Counter({3: 2, 2: 1}); c.subtract(Counter({2: 2})); print(c)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands LOL.. Why is this not the same?? How is the `-` implemented in `collections.Counter`?

Comment: `-` uses `Counter.__sub__()`; `Counter`s are multisets so it makes sense that ordinarily they don't maintain non-positive counts

Comment: For the original method, why not `test = all(fa[entry] <= fb.get(entry, 0) for entry in fa)`? `Counter(somelist)` cannot have negative entries.

Comment: @JimOldfield Because prior to this post I did not know that. But it is not entirely True.. If a `Counter` is a result of its `.subtract` method, it can have negative values.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I only claimed that Counter cannot have negative values *immediately after being constructed with a list*. That is entirely true.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for an implementation of a [multiset](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiset). It should pass (most of) your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically answers by python functions are correct. It seems you also want to check the the number of elements. So, a user defined function will look like

```
def compare(listsuper,listsub):
   stat=None
   for element in listsuper:
       if listsuper.count(element)==listsub.count(element):
          pass
       else:
          stat=False
   if stat==None:
       for element in listsub:
           if element in listsub and element in listsuper:
               pass
           else:
               stat=False
   if stat==None:
       stat=True
   return stat
print compare([2,3,3],[2, 2])
```

Hope this function works as you want